# MySQL query works at MySQL command line but doesn't work with Python

Tags: python, mysql, select

The following query works as expected at MySQL command prompt:

```
select * from users;
```

[image: click to view output of above query]

But, the same query in my following python program returns 0 rowcount. Python program is:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

config = {'user':'user1', 'password':'user1', 'host': '127.0.0.1', 'database': 'user1'}
con = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

if con == None or con == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR or con == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    exit

print(con)

selectrow_users = "SELECT * FROM users"

cursor = con.cursor()
x = cursor.execute(selectrow_users, params=None)
print('rowcount = ', cursor.rowcount)  ## It gives zero

con.close()
```

Output is 0 rowcount:

[image: click to view output of above command]

Comment: Are you certain that you are hitting the same table in both cases, _and_ that nothing is modifying the table contents in between invocations?

Comment: Were you in a transaction when you added the user to the table? Did you commit the transaction?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes Tim. There is only one table in my fresh mysql installation. I have just inserted one row in the table users. There are no other transactions.

Comment: @Barmar, yes Barmar. I have already commit the transaction. Restarted my computer also.

Comment: Still the problem persists. Let me know if someone is facing the same problem and solution if you have..

Comment: This is not a normal problem. You're doing something wrong that you haven't explained in the question.